# how to extract all the href links in a website recursively using request and re module in python?

Tags: python

I have written this python program:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse as urlparse

def extract_links_from(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = response.content
    links = re.findall(r'(?:href=")(.*?)"', content, re.MULTILINE)
    return links

def crawl(url):
    href_links = extract_links_from(url)
    links_list = []
    for link in href_links:
        link = urlparse.urljoin(url, link)
        if "#" in link:
            link = link.split("#")[0]
        if url in link and link not in links_list:
            links_list.append(link)
            print(link)
            crawl(link)

target_url = "https://www.free-power-point-templates.com/"
crawl(target_url)
```

I try to extract all the href links in a website recursively with this program, but when I run this program it just find two links repeatedly and does not find all the links. how should I solve this issue ? please help

I try to find a solution for the issue that exists in the python program that I provided

Comment: You don't ever check to see whether you are fetching a link you have handled before.  A links to B, B links to A, and you have an infinite loop.  So, create `seen = set()`, then check whether you have been there before.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function has no break condition when you're fetching a link you've already checked before and thus goes into an infinite loop. Here's your corrected code:

```
import requests
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse

def extract_links_from(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return []
    content = str(response.content)
    links = re.findall(r'(?:href=")(.*?)"', content, re.MULTILINE)
    return links

def crawl(url, domain, visited=set(), max_depth=5):
    if max_depth == 0 or url in visited:
        return []

    visited.add(url)
    href_links = extract_links_from(url)
    links_list = []

    for link in href_links:
        link = urljoin(url, link.split("#")[0])
        if urlparse(link).netloc == domain and link not in visited:
            links_list.append(link)
            links_list.extend(crawl(link, domain, visited, max_depth - 1))
    return links_list

target_url = "https://www.free-power-point-templates.com/"
parsed_url = urlparse(target_url)
domain = parsed_url.netloc

result = crawl(target_url, domain)
print(result)
```